# How much space does my Debian OS need

Tags: debian, partition, disk-usage, embedded, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone, with 4GB of internal emmc.

When I install a Debian image on it from its site and run command *df -h* , the result is below. /dev/mmcblk1p1 shows that it uses 3.4G of memory. What I don't understand, is this the total amount of memory required by the Debian operating system?, so it means that I have only 600MB of free space remaining in the emmc to install other stuff etc. or part of the 3.4G for the operating system is also for use to install other files etc.?, I've never understood this properly

The problem is, I now want to clone a repository of size 1.4G , but it reports that there is no space left on the device. Am I completely out of space, or is there a way around this?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            215M     0  215M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  6.1M   43M  13% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.6G  3.4G     0 100% /
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 3):

As shown by the `df` command, your `/dev/mmcblk1p1` is full.

Your partition's size is 3.6G (Size), you're using 3.4G (Used). There's no more space available (`Avail` shows 0 and `Use%` shows 100%).

`Size` is the actual partition's size.
`Used` is the number of bytes used.
`Avail` is the number of bytes available.
`Use%` is the space percentage used.

`man df` can help you.